# VB.NET Drawing Multiple Images onto a PictureBox at Different Locations

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, gdi+, system.drawing

I have an Image inside a `PictureBox` and I have several other images that I want to draw onto the `PictureBox` at different locations.

For example, I have several images I want to draw onto a picture inside a `PictureBox` like these two stars (both are individual pictures (PNG) with transparent backgrounds):

[image: star]

I would like to draw multiple of these different stars at separate locations, pictured by an example on the picture below. (The US map is the image already present inside the `PictureBox`.

[image: imgUS]

I'm trying to write a function that when supplied/given a `Point` variable of the `PictureBox`'s `x` and `y` values and the location of the image (such as `My.Resources.RedCity` or `My.Resources.BlueCity`) would draw the multiple images onto a `PictureBox`.

So far, I've accomplished to draw **ONE** picture onto the `picturebox`, but I am not able to draw multiple onto a `PictureBox` at different locations at one time since the other image disappears when I invalidate the image.

I was thinking of writing a function something like this to add a Picture/Point to some list or something and having something under the `PictureBox`'s `paint` event, but I'm not sure how it would work for this.

Is there any function that exists or can be written that can be written that would be able to draw multiple images onto a `PictureBox` at different locations at the same time?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking of writing a function something like this to add a
> Picture/Point to some list or something and having something under the
> PictureBox's paint event, but I'm not sure how it would work for this.

That's exactly the correct approach.  Simple example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private dataPoints As New List(Of Tuple(Of Point, Integer))

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        dataPoints.Add(Tuple.Create(New Point(nudX.Value, nudY.Value), If(cbBlue.Checked, 0, 1)))
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        Dim G As Graphics = e.Graphics
        For Each dataPoint In dataPoints
            Dim img As Image = If(dataPoint.Item2 = 0, My.Resources.BlueCity, My.Resources.RedCity)
            G.DrawImage(img, dataPoint.Item1)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is there a way I could specify how to Overlap a specific image with a priority? For example if the red stars were drawn in around the same location as the blue stars, the blue stars would remain on top?

Comment: Sure you could do two passes through your List and paint all Red stars first, then Blue stars next, making the Blue on top.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the map into a Graphics environment, and then draw on top of it.

Below is an example of how to draw a string (which can be rotated on the map), and the two zeroes on the end of gr.DrawString(,,,,0,0) place the string in the upper left corner).  FromImage(bmp) is where you can load your US map, just import bmp to the file path using the map's file address, or add it to resources.  I would add colored stars and circles from Wingding fonts, which have different shaped characters, which you only need to change their color.   I provided the font size, so you have to play with it.

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(500, 15)
Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
gr.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
Dim mybrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Yellow)
Dim fontbrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
fontbrush.Color = SystemColors.ControlText
mybrush.Color = SystemColors.Control
Dim sfont As New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Regular)
Dim strformat As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical)
strformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
Dim strToDraw As String
strToDraw = "Test string"
Dim stringSize As New SizeF()
stringSize = gr.MeasureString(strToDraw, sfont)
gr.FillRectangle(mybrush, CInt(0), CInt(0), stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height)
gr.DrawString(strToDraw, sgenefont, fontbrush, 0, 0)
gr.Dispose
```